# How to get onUploadProgress value in an await function from axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm relatively new to react and having trouble getting the progress value "progressEvent" of axios in the onUploadProgress callback,

I have two files, one for the api call and one for my react component:

Here is a sample of my api.js

```
function uploadImage(file) {
        return axios.post('/api/media_objects', file, {
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
                let percentComplete = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                console.log(percentComplete);
            }
        }).then(response => response.data.id);
    }
```

and my try/catch from the component

```
try {
    const upload = await xxxAPI.uploadImage(formData);

} catch (error) {

    console.log(error);
}
```

How can i retrieve in the "try" the "percentComplete" ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, I'd advise using some kind of state management (redux/mobx) for controlling this flow. Not to handle it directly from a React component. So the component will trigger a kind of action and the upload process will be handled outside.

But, for a very simple solution, you'd need something like this:

```js
function uploadImage(file, updateProgress) {
  return axios.post('/api/media_objects', file, {
    onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
      let percentComplete = progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total
      percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
      console.log(percentComplete);
      updateProgress(percentComplete);
    }
  }).then(response => response.data.id);
}

    const MyComponent = () => {
       const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
       
       const onUpload = useCallback(() => {
             myApi.uploadImage(data, setProgress);
       },[]);

       return <div>
                   <span>Uploaded: {progress}</span>
                   <button onClick={onUpload}>Upload</button>
             </div>;
    };
```

the progress value is stored in the component's state so it can be updated and rendered.

I would also put the try/catch in the API method rather than in the component.

On a more general note. I'd advise using a library such as [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady) to manage the upload for you. There's are a lot of edge cases and functionality you need to handle typically when uploading files and a small 3rd party like Uploady takes care of it for you: [Preview with progress for file uploading in React](https://medium.com/@poeticGeek/preview-with-progress-for-file-uploading-in-react-547b66aae41b)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your help ! You are right about Redux, we are planning to implement it soon. I still have an error about the "updateProgress(percentComplete);" on the api side. I get "updateProgress is not a function", do you know how to solve this ?

Comment: Ok, i managed to make it work,  i changed "myApi.uploadImage(data, setProgress)" by "myApi.uploadImage(data, callback);" and i change my state after with the callback value. Put directly setProgress was the problem i dont know why.. Again thanks a lot for your time and i will study the libs you provide me :)